# Execute a Query/StoredProcedure that is stored as a field value in a database table with PHP and JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

What I am trying to achieve is a bit complicated so I will try to explain as simple as possible.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76ju0g52/) just to give you an idea of what I want to show
when you click on the DIV, it will toggle another DIV with information inside(which is being fetched from a database table that I have control of) that's where I want to display the "TIME" from the **telephony** table!

thanks in advance, if I need to clarify things please let me know because I'm really stuck!

I have the two tables and servers below:

```
connection server 1: mario2001
table: overlays
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| q_id | button    |                query                                                     |                                                                                              
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   12 | AHT_Stats | CALL telephony.sp_get_spec_stat_all_agents( '2014-11-02', '2014-11-02' ) |      
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**I only have READ privilege on the server/table below**

```
connection server 2: mario2003
table: telephony
+-------------+
| memo | time |  
+-------------+
| JOE  | 410  |
+-------------+
```

**Problem:**

I want to know if its possible (if it is how?) to execute the query in the table **overlays** by clicking a HTML button with a onClick event. Now, I know that I need JQuery, AJAX and/or JS for that. I am not very good at them and that's where I need help. The STORED PROCEDURE in my "overlays" table is getting the results from the "telephony" table.

**map.php(everything displayed here)getting my StoredProcedure field value and store it as variable:**

```
    //Overlay table
    $query_overlay_sql    = "SELECT query FROM overlays";
    $query_overlay_result = mysqli_query($dbh1,$query_overlay_sql);

    //get the query from the "query" field in the overlay table 
    //and store it as a variable for later use for the AHT button
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(($query_overlay_result))){
        $sp_value = $row['query']; 
    }
```

**HTML/JQuery:**

```
 <!-- show the results in this DIV below-->
 <div id="resultdiv" class="resultdiv" style="display:none">Time: <? /* get the time value*/ ?></div>   

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    var sp_value_to_send = <?php echo $sp_value; ?>;
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data: { sp_value: sp_value_to_send }, // pass data here
                    success : function(data){
                        $('#resultdiv').show();
                      $('#resultdiv').html(data);
                    }//end success
                })//end ajax
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
        </script>
```

**show_aht.php:**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn_retca2003.php';


/****************************************************
Execute the query_value when AHT button is clicked
/****************************************************/
 $dbh2_result = mysqli_query($dbh2, $query_value) 
 or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

//loop the result set

 while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbh2_result)){   
    $memo  = $row2['memo_code'];
  $time  = $row2['avg_handle_time'];
  echo '<p>memo: '. $memo . ' time:' . $time . '</p><br>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: So, attempting AJAX didn't work for you?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I updated my code, still im stuck, not sure how to pass my sp_value to the other page to it will display back the query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a config item to pass the data -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#aht').click(function(){
        var sp_value_to_send = <?php echo $foo; ?>;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url : "show_aht.php",
            data: { sp_value: sp_value_to_send }, // pass data here
            success : function(data){
                $('#resultdiv').show();
                $('#resultdiv').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The value will now be available in the `$_POST['sp_value']` variable in show_aht.php. You can use it just as you would any other variable.

Once your AJAX call is setup correctly you will be able to watch the request / response in your browser's console. That way you can verify that the AJAX request is sending the right data and that you're then receiving the right data back from the request.

Once other note: I placed your code in a document ready handler because I was unsure where your code was placed in the general layout of the page. You should get in the habit of using a document ready handler, even if you place your jQuery code just before the closing `</body>` tag.

You'll receive data back in the `success : function(data)` function. The returned information will be in `data` which can be used in your page for many purposes, including display as you have done with `#resultdiv`

Comment: thanks! I had the document.ready I just didnt include it.I see an error in the console, it says **Expected ';'** between **CALL** and **sp_get_spec_stat_all_agents('2014-11-02', '2014-11-02');** which is the the value of sp_value_to send. Also, how can I use the data being sent to execute my query on the show_aht.php and send back the result to display in my #aht DIV? not very familiar with AJAX.  thanks again  I updated my JS code above

Comment: I edited my answer @mario. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: ok now I understand. Still, I can't get rid of that error message in the console my script is not running because of it

Comment: just the JS. it says SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'   like so: CALL ";" sp_blabla

Comment: does it give you a line number? Also add one after the AJAX function `})`

Comment: yes line 509, right after "CALL" . I added the semicolon after AJAX function still the error occurs

Comment: That's the PHP file, not the javascript file. What is the output of `$sp_value`?

Comment: hmm...will try to see where the error is, it says its after "CALL" since its the variable im trying to pass. thanks for your help and time , I appreciate it!

Comment: I found the error. I put double quotes on the sp_value_to_send and it worked